# Pandas groupby, calculating mean seperately for subgroups (eg gender)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

my goal is to group jobs by their respective group (eg "Sales" for all types of sales roles) and calculate the mean for males and females. Example code is:

```
dict = {
    'Job Group': ['Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales'],
    'Job Role': ['Junior Account Manager', 'Junior Account Manager', 'Senior Account Manager', 'Senior Account Manager', 'Senior Account Manager'],
    'Female Salary': [0, 0, 0, 100000, 0],
    'Male Salary': [80000, 80000, 80000, 0, 100000]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
grouped = df.groupby(['Job Group'], as_index = False, sort = False)[['Male Salary', 'Female Salary']].agg({'Male Salary': 'mean', 'Female Salary': 'mean'}).fillna(0)

print(df)
print(grouped)
```

The outcome is:

```
  Job Group  Male Salary  Female Salary
0     Sales        68000          20000
```

What I need however is a result based on the average of the salary per sex (4 males (340000 / 4), 1 female (100000 / 1):

```
Job Group  Male Salary  Female Salary
0     Sales        85000          100000
```

Unfortunately, when I group employees by Job Group and calculate the means for male salary and female salary, the two salary groups are calculated based on the number of ALL employees in the respective group although I would need the mean calculated within their sex group: Example: when I have 10 employees in Sales (9 male / 1 female), the mean of the female salary (100k USD) gets calculated as 100.000 / 10 = 10.000 USD, which is not correct.

A (work around) solution could be to split the df into two dataframes (for male and female employees), perform "groupby" for each to get the means and then merge the dfs. There should be a more elegant way, i suppose.

Could you share / point me to a solution that you have found for this situation?
Thank you!

Comment: Sending your input data format and some reproducible code would be helpful

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal, I have added an example as requested. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can try using np.where to get a column which says whether row is male or female. Then can group by job group and sex.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `0` to `np.nan` before computing the averages:

```py
print(
    df.replace(0, np.nan)
    .groupby("Job Group", as_index=False)
    .agg({"Female Salary": "mean", "Male Salary": "mean"})
)
```

Prints

```
  Job Group  Female Salary  Male Salary
0     Sales       100000.0      85000.0
```

Comment: Veľká vďaka, Andrej!